# How to reduce width of rectangle in EaselJS animation

Tags: canvas, easeljs

I want to reduce the width of a rectangle every tick in an animation.

In the init() method, I initially create the rectangle with:

```
var graphics = new createjs.Graphics().beginFill("green").drawRect(650, 90, 280, 8);
var shape = new createjs.Shape(graphics);
stage.addChild(shape);
```

How can I access the width of the rectangle in tick()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple answer: You can't do this directly!

There are two ways to do this:

**1) Through scaleX and Tween**

```
var tween = createjs.Tween.get(shape).to({scaleX:0.5 }, 1000);
```

**2) Through redrawing every frame**

Save an additional variable with the initial width, then subtract something from that width on every tick and redraw the rectangle with the new width.

While way **1)** is probably simpler, scaling **might** result in blurry edges, you'd have to test that in your case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I want to make sure I know how to redraw every frame before I move on to tween. I tried to redraw the rectangle every frame in tick, and it works, but how do I clear the existing rectangle at the start of every tick? I tried stage.removeChild(shape) with no luck.

Comment: Just use `shape.graphics.clear()` to clear the existing rectangle and then then use the existing shape to draw the new one: `shape.graphics.beginFill("green").dr... ect`   ( http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/Graphics.html#method_clear )

Comment: For anyone stumbling across this, there is an easier way than redrawing entirely: commands. http://blog.createjs.com/new-command-approach-to-easeljs-graphics/